# Click on a link in a table based on the other text in the row in selenium IDE 2

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and have very little coding experience.  That being said, I am trying to set up a suite of regression tests for my software.  I run into a problem when making a test to add and save a new contact and information, then immediately delete the contact (just to make sure any new additions to the software don't break that functionality).  My contacts are saved into a table with the name in the first column, details in the second, edit link in the third, delete link in the fourth, and assign contact link in the fifth.  Everything works fine right after I set up the test, but the IDE assigns what delete link to click with an xpath so if i add another contact before my test contact, the wrong one gets deleted.  How do I target the delete link in my test contact row so it will search for the text "test contact" and click the delete link in the same row everytime even if i have changed the order of the contacts in the table or added many new contacts? Below is a sample of one row in the table.  I need to select delete based on the name in that row.

```
<table class="tbl">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="entityLink" target="_attached" href="../download/Average+Inspection.xlam?documentID=55840"> Average Inspection.xlam </a>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>43.76 Kb</td>
<td>SP: Randi kay Anderson</td>
<td>5/16/14 1:13 PM</td>
<td> No </td>
<td>
<ul class="actlinks llink">
<li>
<a class="al-assign" target="_top" href="/app/admin/massAssignFiles.do?m=massAssignSLFileAttachment&returnPage=BACK_ADMIN_SEARCH_UPLOADEDFILE&documentID=55840"> Assign </a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="al-delete" onclick="return myConfirm();" href="/app/admin/manageFiles.do?m=deleteFile&documentID=55840">Delete</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="al-edit" href="/app/admin/manageFiles.do?m=editFile&fileid=55840">Edit</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="al-edit" target="_top" href="sharingPermissions.do?m=editFileSharingPermissions&returnPage=BACK_ADMIN_SEARCH_UPLOADEDFILE&fileID=55840">Edit Sharing Permissions</a>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you can share the html of the table.

Comment: You should read [ask] and clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

What I feel, there should be some uniqueness among the entries of table.So you should use that unique property to locate and perform action on your required element.

By looking into above table, I assume that `?documentID=55840` is that unique property for each table and you can use this to locate the required element. The only thing you have to add in your code is , after adding a new entry your code should be able to obtain the `documentId` of newly added entry.

You can do it in following steps:

- Add a new entry
- Obtain the document Id of newly added entry
- Using the document Id locate the delete element

  ```
   // Given text should be dynamic to make it generic
   String hrefOfElememnt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Average Inspection.xlam')]")).getAttribute("href");
   String[] hrefArray= hrefOfElememnt .split("?");
   String[] documentIdArray = hrefArray[1].split("=");
   String documentId = documentIdArray [1];

   // To find delete button
   WebElement deleteLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='al-delete' and contains(@href,'"+ documentId +"')]"));
   deleteLink.click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use this

command- click
target- xpath=//*[text()="text you want to click"]

I used it, this will solve your problem

Comment: I am able to use that to locate Average Inspection.xlam in the above table, xpath=//*[text()="Average Inspection.xlam"]how do I get it to click on the "DELETE" link in the same row?